# Sensor data missing in Ubuntu 14.04 on GA970A-D3P board

Tags: temperature, amd-processor, sensors

I am unable to access most sensor data in Ubuntu using Psensor or Xsensors on  Ubuntu 14.04 on GA-970A-D3P board with an AMD FX 6350 CPU. I cannot access GPU temperature, the individual temperature of each CPU core,  fan speeds or voltages.

I also cannot display SPD Data during memtest, I get “SMbus Controller Not Known” though I was able to get that data in Ubuntu using decode-dimms.

I can however, access the overall temperature and CPU usage. On “System monitor” I can get the CPU history of each core.  Running 'sensors-detect' did not allow access to remaining sensors either.

This is a dual boot machine with windows 7. On Windows I can access GPU temperature and fan speed, overall 1 – 6 CPU temperature (but not each individual core temperature), GPU voltages and clock speeds and SPD Data.

Can anyone suggest a fix?

Comment: I'm guessing you installed lm-sensors because you ran sensors-detect. Is this correct?

Comment: also, can you access these values using the `sensors` command

Comment: Yes lm-sensors was the lates version when i checked before. `Sensors` only shows `power 1` and `temp 1` when i do `sensors`.

Answer (score 0):

The package responsible for detecting sensors in 14.04 is **libsensors4** which is developed together with **lm-sensors** and **sensors-detect**. People there are really trying hard to keep pace with new hardware integration but this will not always include all possible sensors out there.

From an [overview of supported devices](http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/Devices) we have the impression that the AMD 'Vishera' processors were not yet included. Nevertheless it may be worth to try a nupgrade both **libsensors**, and **sensors-detect** to the [most recent version](http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/Download) if running on newer hardware.

There is no guarantee that sensors of a specifc device will be detected thenafter. We can not test this here for obvious reasons.

Also note that [updating the package included in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lm-sensors) may need considerable time to include newer upstream releases. At the time of writing the upstream stable version is a 3.4.0 (released 4 days ago) whereas the version from 14.04 still is a 3.3.4.

Comment: libsensors4 is already the latest version

Comment: as said, it may not be supported then (I am sadly having the same issue with  AMD A8-6500 on a Gigabyte  GA-F2A88XN)